# Wordpress Ratings?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, rating, rate

Thank you for viewing my post..
I am currently working on my blog, it is about writing reviews and rating books, and movies.
I have searched for hours for a rating plugin for ME to rate movies and books posts,
but all I found was plugins for visitors for rating posts.

It came as frustrating as hell, I hated wordpress.
I am thinking about going blogspot, but I would have wasted like 12 hours working on wordpress.

So, please any ideas or good/reliable plugin for me to rate movies and books inside my posts, without any involvement from the visitors.

Thank you.

Comment: Well plugins are not made for things which can be done directly. Just edit the post and write your rating. U may keep a snippet to copy and paste from. Wordpress s/w is the best but hosting has limited features.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the 'advanced custom fields' plugin and create a field for posts called rating. Then within the single template add some php to see if that field has a value. If it has display the review. You can style the review as you like it within that area.

If you wanted to use a couple of fields, 1 for star rating and 1 for comment that can easily be achieved within that if..loop.

example of loop :

```
   <?php
   // check if there is a rating
   if(get_field('rating',$id) != '') { ?>
       <div class="rating">
       I rate this : <?php echo get_field('rating',$id); ?> Stars
       </div>
   <?php
   }
   // check if there is a review
   if(get_field('review',$id) != '') { ?>
      <div class="review">
      <h4>My Review</h4>
      <?php echo get_field('review',$id); ?>
      </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Using the above you would need 2 advanced fields with the names 'rating' and 'review'
This will check if either exist and if they do for that post display them within the divs on your page.

I hope this helps as an easy solution..

Comment: It seeems, amazing :), but how do i use it ?!

Comment: do you mean how does the plugin work or where to add this code?

Comment: how does the plugin work, :(

Comment: Im guessing you have installed the plugin.. go to the menu for custom fields, click add new.. You can pretty much leave as is the options although you can change fields for different post categories or page templates. Click the button add field in bottom left of top box and fill in the required fields... choose texarea for review and text box or select box for stars.. save/update the custom field. Now when you go onto a post at the bottom of the screen below the textarea should be the custom fields you have just created. Just add content to the fields for the required posts.

Comment: Using the code above which needs to be within the post loop those fields will now appear.. (if you cant see the custom fields on the post page go to screen options at the top and click them within that menu to make them appear)